# Trouble posting to database with a form

Tags: php, mysql, database, post

I have a simple form with some PHP code to post to a database some simple information.

The connection to the database is just fine because it display items I have manually entered exactly how I want it to; however. I cannot get it to post from the form into the database. I have tinkered with a lot of code with no luck. Anyone see anything I'm missing? Here is the code:

```
<center>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">

    <strong><h2><br><br>Enter in my guestbook!</h2></strong><br>
    <h3>Nickname:</h3><input type="text" name="guestbook_name" maxlength="25"><br>
    <h3>Write About Your Day:</h3><textarea name="guesbook_message" rows="6" cols="60"       maxlength="255"></textarea><br>
    <input type ="submit" value="POST">

</form>

<br>
<hr>
<br>

<?php

    if (mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') && mysql_select_db('mydb')) {

    //echo 'Connected to the database!';

    $time = gmdate("l dS \of F Y h:i:s A");
    $errors = array();

    if (isset($_POST['guestbook_name'], $_POST['guestbook_message'])) {

        echo 'Set data!';

        $guestbook_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(     $_POST['guestbook_name'])); 
        $guestbook_message = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(     $_POST['guestbook_message'])); 

        if (empty($guestbook_name) || empty($guestbook_message)) {
        $errors[] = 'All fields are required.';
        }

        if (strlen($guestbook_name)>25 || strlen($guestbook_message)>250){
        $errors[] = 'One or more fields exceeded the character limit!'; 
        }

        if (empty($erros)) {
            $insert = "INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES     ('','$time','$guestbook_name','$guestbook_message')";
            if (mysql_query($insert)){
                 header ('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            } else {
                $errors[] = 'Something went wrong. Try again.';
            }

        } else {
            foreach($errors as $error) {
                echo'<p><strong>'.$error.'</strong></p>'; 
            }

        }

    }

    // display entries 
    $entries = mysql_query("SELECT timestamp, name, message FROM guestbook ORDER BY timestamp DESC");

    if (mysql_num_rows($entries)==0){
        echo 'No entries, yet.';
        } else { 
            //echo 'Entries found.'; 

            while ($entries_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($entries)){
                $entries_timestamp = $entries_row['timestamp'];
                $entries_name = $entries_row['name'];
                $entries_message = $entries_row['message'];
                echo '<p><strong>Posted by '.$entries_name.' on     '.$entries_timestamp.'</strong>:<br><br>'.$entries_message.'</p><br><br>';

            }
        }

} else {
    echo 'Could not connect at this time.';
} 


?>

</center>
```

My main issue is the submitting the database, any help would be great, thanks!

Kyle B.

Comment: Is your unique identifier an auto-incremental field?

Comment: BTW if you want the form to go to the current page that you are on you can simply leave the form action blank.

Comment: What happens when you try to insert something? Do you get an error? Does the mysql-query INSERT-statement execute? Try debugging to see the value of the `$insert` variable.

Comment: Try copying the insert query to phpmyadmin or some other tool and run it. Do you get an error. Does mysql_error() return anything?

Comment: Could you update your post with the changes you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will need to see your database table structure vs. your insert sql statement to see if you are inserting properly.

Most likely cause of failed insert is not setting a field value which is set to NOT NULL, (either by not inserting a value, or having an empty/mistyped variable).

But more common problems are:

```
wrong table or field names
not having the enough privelages on your database user account
```

Comment: id is a int(11) with auto increment and primary key, timestamp is a varchar(40), name is varchar(32) and message is varchar(255). The inserts work fine outside of the logic I have in place for error handeling, which was accomplished thorough a tutorial. Basically is it either to do with my post, or my logic in error handling, but I have experimented with no success

Comment: @KyleBegeman change your `INSERT` statement to include the col names, e.g. `INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1, col2, col3, etc) VALUES ($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4);` Btw, as of MySQL 5.5 `TIMESTAMP` is a reserved word, so you will need to surround it by \` quotes each time you use it. phpMyAdmin automatically adds the \` quotes for you, this may be why it works in phpMyAdmin but not in your own php code. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Thanks Ozzy, I applied the change and its still not working but your addition is a great one! I am convinced it is the logic for checking errors that just is not firing properly, so I will have to rework that I suppose

Answer (score 0):

A typo perhaps?

```
if (empty($erros)) {
```

I believe the correct name is $errors
(note the R)

Comment: I am not receiving any errors actually, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: I corrected errors which was a great find, but still no posting. My unique identifier is auto increment, and if I just do a plain insert, it inserts perfectly into the database so I believe it has to do with my code checking for no errors

Comment: Also, the error messages are not displaying when I leave the fields blank either, so I'm assuming the issue must lie within that logic of the code.

Comment: Does my form need to be changed?

Comment: I think it would help you if you would add some echo-statements for debugging in your code, so that you can find out where the logic goes wrong. Also do a `print_r($errors);` before the `if(empty($errors))` statement.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to this line

Comment: if (isset($_POST['guestbook_name'], $_POST['guestbook_message']))     {

            echo 'Set data!';

Comment: So basically it is having issues with the POST method.

Comment: Then show us the HTML-form that's supposed to send the data to this PHP-file.